# I need to calculate what 230,769 is 20% of.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to calculate what 230,769 is 20% of.  I know I can multiply 230,769  x 5.  But I'd like to know what the algebraic formula is.

Comment: You want 100%. This is **five times** of 20%. Thus you have to muliply 230,769 by 5.

Comment: $230769\times5$ _is_ an algebraic formula for what  $230,769$ is $20\%$ of. If you're looking for something with letters instead of just numbers, you probably have a more general problem in mind than specifically twenty percent of the specific number $230,769.$ Do you want a formula that works for any starting number (so you can replace $230,769$ with something else), for any percentage, or for any combination of the two things?

Answer (score 4):

Let $230769$ be $20\%$ of $x$. Then
$$
\frac{230769}{x} = \frac{20}{100}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Typhon i don't hold that doing all the work for the OP is what should be done -- I gave a hint, and let the OP do at least something to get his homework problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at it. Your problem is: 
$$
0.2 \quad \text{of} \quad \text{'what number'} \quad \text{equals} \quad 230,769
$$

Which translates to:
$$
0.2 \cdot x = 230,769
$$